# local variable 'bet' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, web-crawler

It seems like some websites are giving no output for variable bet.
Mentioned website is only one of those I am trying
    _

```
cleaner('http://www.indeed.com/cmp/Akvelon,-Inc./jobs/Software-Database-Engineer-9f35bfbe02577e2a?sjdu=QwrRXKrqZ3CNX5W-O9jEvRFd8FQI4DEv5V74lSpSnHYgnddE4ZyZFNs76EkGRtDwtEmC1g0ZgP9j4kJzAk16Kmc5zfQEpyLY32nEHt1W9y4')
    def _cleaner(websr):
        html = urllib2.urlopen(websr).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        for elm in soup.find("span", id="job_summary").find_all("p"):
            betf = elm.get_text()
        for i in soup.find("span", id="job_summary").find_all("ul"):
            bet = i.get_text(" ")
        return betf+" "+bet
```

Comment: What is the question? You keep going whether or not `bet` is defined, and you are getting the error when you try to use it... What did you expect it to be?

Comment: @Selcuk I have edited the question

Comment: Still you won't have a `bet` object if `for` loop never runs (ie. there is no `span` with an id `job_summary`). You have to decide what you will do in such a case. Hiding the error won't do good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lists (`soup.find("span", id="job_summary".find_all("p")`) in the `for` loops may be empty causing `bet` or `betf` not to be assigned. You could assign the variables beforehand to avoid this problem:

```
def _cleaner(website):
    betf = ''
    bet = ''
    html = urllib2.urlopen(website).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for elm in soup.find("span", id="job_summary").find_all("p"):
        betf = elm.get_text()
    for i in soup.find("span", id="job_summary").find_all("ul"):
        bet = i.get_text()
    return betf+" "+bet
```

Comment: I have edited the question. It was not containing try and error earlier. The error was before that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the assignment to `bet` is in a `try` block within a loop, `soup.find("span", id="job_summary").find_all("ul")` must be non-empty and `i.get_text()` must succeed at least once for `bet` to be assigned a value. You should determine what you want to do in cases where this fails. You can assign a default value in the `except` block, or simply assign something before the loop. The same goes for `betf` above.

Comment: I have edited the question. It was not containing try and error earlier. The error was before that.

Comment: @dsl1990 - The first thing I say in this answer is "Since the assignment to `bet` is in a `try` block **within a loop, `soup.find("span", id="job_summary").find_all("ul")` must be non-empty**..."